# SOCKS5 proxy does not work on chromium browsers but only certain websites

Tags: networking

I have a socks 5 proxy set up using ssh on a vps. Recently clients have been unable to connect using any chromium based browser (specifically chrome, opera and vivaldi). I'm assuming its because of a recent update but am not sure. The latest versions which I downloaded to test all don't work. The instructions that used to work are here: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/socks-proxy For some reason, it only affects some websites but not others. google works, as does whatismyip.com. Yahoo and ebay were two examples that don't work. As far as I can tell, it seems that the connections start, it receives some data (on the order of hundreds of bytes), then just stops receiving data.

Even more strangely, the proxy works perfectly fine on Firefox and MS Edge.

I'm pretty lost at this point. My next step is to try older versions of chromium, but am hoping someone else might have an idea.

Comment: Is it perhaps choking on QUIC (UDP/443), HTTP/2 or Speedy, or perhaps even Websockets?

Comment: Any ideas on how to test that? It should work fine for any tcp or udp connection...

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm also having trouble with a socks 5 proxy in Chrome. It works in Firefox, and it used to work in Chrome, but it just suddenly doesn't anymore.

Comment: Yes. My provider had a DNS outage, and Chrome defaults to DNS over SOCKS5 instead of locally. Firefox, on the other hand, defaults to local DNS when using SOCKS. See: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=725362#c8 Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try an extension for proxy in Chrome. I use **FoxyProxy Standard** in Chrome with ssh tunneled socks5 proxy.